# SQL table design for best performance

Tags: sql-server, query-performance

I am designing an MVC asp.net Web App to manage bookings on several restaurants.

My main concern is DB performance when the user wants to get all the bookings, for a specific day, for a specific restaurant.

I have one table with the following columns/data types:

- [Id] - int
- [RestaurantId] - int
- [StartDateTime] - datetime
- [ServiceDuration] - int
- [WorkerId] - nvarchar(128)
- [ServiceId] - int
- [CostumerId] - int
- [Notes] - nvarchar(128)

I am trying to find out if having just one table like this, that can have a very big amount of rows, is the best DB design approach

One alternative is to have a second table with just the columns I need for the query since I read on SO that more tables with less columns is better than less tables with more columns:

- [Id] - int
- [RestaurantId] - int
- [StartDateTime] - datetime
- [BookingId] - int (that points to a booking id on the first table)

Comment: Pick one RDBMS.  I'm removing [mysql] since your syntax implies sql-server.

Answer (score 0):

In my view, [the design of the table is normalized](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/abhijit_desai/2010/09/07/noramlization/) and all is okay. What you can do is just a covered index for field `StartDateTime` like that:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_YourTable_StartDateTime_RestaurantId_BookingId_Id  ]
ON dbo.YourTable
(StartDateTime, RestaurantId, BookingId, Id)
GO
```

With that index you will have **index seek** in your query plan when you will write your desired query:

```
Select 
  RestaurantId
, BookingId
, Id
YourTable
WHERE StartDateTime = '...'
```

**Pay great attention to the order of columns in the index** `(StartDateTime, RestaurantId, BookingId, Id)`. If you move `StartDateTime` to the NOT first position, then you will not have index seek.

Comment: Thanks for coming up with the covered index concept that I didn't know. I am going to investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

One table is fine.

If you only need the 4 fields in your daily booking report have just them in the SELECT clause of the sql so its just the relevant fields returned to you so minimising the date transferred to you.

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario is one for which a standard three table design with a junction table would probably make the most sense.  I suggest two tables for restaurants and bookings:

```
Restaurant
    id
    name
    type
    notes

Booking
    id
    date
```

Then, create a third *junction* table which relates restaurants to their bookings:

```
RestaurantBooking
    restaurant_id
    booking_id
    PK (restaurant_id, booking_id)
```

This is a normalized approach, and it lets you store restaurant bookings in an efficient way, without repeating metadata from either side of the relationship.

To find all bookings for a given restaurant today, you might try:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM Booking b
INNER JOIN RestaurantBooking rb
    ON b.id = rb.booking_id
INNER JOIN Restaurant r
    ON rb.restaurant_id = r.id
WHERE
    r.name = 'Tavern on the Green' AND
    b.date = CAST(GETDATE() AS date);
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, that makes sense. Following your approach, in order to get the bookings for a restaurant, for a day, I will need: 1-find in Booking table, all the bookings for all restaurants for a specific day; 2-filter all bookings for the restaurant I need. Am i thinking right?

Comment: @myusername21 I have given you a sample query for your first scenario.  I leave the other scenario to you as homework.

Comment: Thank you very much! :)